# Xcode 7 crash with git

Tags: xcode, git, xcode7

Xcode 7 crashes every time, when I try to commit changes on a specific project. I tried to remove the xcuserdata from project package, as fount on this [link](http://pinkstone.co.uk/xcode-crashes-every-time-you-open-it-and-how-to-fix-it/). I uploaded the crash report.
[crash report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrjbL.png).

Is the only [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980108/xcode-crashes-when-working-with-repository) to restart a brand new project, copy all files, start a new repository and losing all commits done till now?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a workaround for the described crash. As following the advices given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455903/xcode-crashing-when-opening-project-file).

Here my steps:

- First: I deleted the xcuserdata in the project package
- Second: I deleted the xcuserdata in the project.workspace as well
- the DerivedData folder
- and as last step I cleaned the project inside Xcode.

  This solved the crash. May it helps someone with the same issue!